# Is Pentaho BI suite's iPhone-targeted code still maintained?

Tags: iphone, pentaho

The BI platform [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com) 1.7 used to have an extension that allowed applications to be accessed from iPhone:
http://www.pentaho.com/launch/iPhone

Is it still maintained?
If so, is it available in the Community Edition?

Answer (score 0):

Their iPhone/iPad code is still maintained as far as I can tell, but only available in the Enterprise Edition.

That said, there is an Open Source Android app available here:
  http://code.google.com/p/pentaho-android/

Your mileage may vary, some restrictions apply, etc, etc. =p

Comment: "as far as you can tell" = did you try on Pentaho 3.x? I have a trial of Enterprise Edition and it did not work when I installed it (could be my mistake).

Comment: From what I read, the iPhone/iPad code is supported in the 3.x line.  Considering the code's press release was in May, it's safe to say that the code is supported.

http://www.pentaho.com/news/releases/20100525_pentaho_ipad_for_bi.php